# Magento2 Cron Script error

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, script, php-extension

I'm getting following errors as soon as I connected with the marketplace it's asking me to install 56 extensions and I'm trying to install them and getting the error in the first image.

2nd Image the module manager has FATAL ERROR don't know how to resolve them.

Thanks in advance guys :)

[image]

Also getting this error in Module Manger 
[image]

Comment: Check the mysql connection and MySQL user has proper access or not?

Comment: How do I check that? As of now the wamp server is running at full and the icon is green

Comment: try to install magento via  command line `php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=root \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1`  https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-install-via-composer-and-command-line-cli/

Comment: Magento already been installed so now again I should try to install or what? I'm sorry I'm unable to understand it properly.